# UFW block port UDP 67 on all but specific interfaces?

Tags: ufw

I am new to UFW, trying to quit iptables for something that appears to be a lot easier at face value.

I am just trying to get my head around the logic and do not know much about it yet.

I have a global listening UDP port 67 that I am unable to disable due to configuration issues with a 3rd party application.

so the plan is to block this port on all but a specific interface / IP, it's still needed on only one side of the network.

How would I do this using UFW? let's say the interface I want to allow is eth0 with the static IP 192.168.0.50

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ufw allow on eth0 to any port 67 proto udp
```

[Ubuntu UFW documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)
[UFW Cheatsheet by @rstp](https://blog.rtsp.us/ufw-uncomplicated-firewall-cheat-sheet-a9fe61933330)

Comment: ah ok.... do i need to deny all first?

Comment: I think UFW denies by default but this is something you can test with telnet to verify. But yes normally you would start with deny all.